# How to add a download button or custom layout in center of progress bar?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to create a custom progress bar to display downloading progress with an icon and textview in center of it.

There are libraries and some samples but only with textview inside progress bar so how do i add this imageview also? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You should create customView. In your customView will be textView, and you will add circle and arrow in the `onDraw` method. 
In this code I show you process of drawing circle

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.lucid.dreaming.ui.guide.views.CustomView
            android:id="@+id/custom_view"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/big_padding"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/custom_view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/custom_view"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/custom_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/custom_view" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here I added CountDownTimer, which will show work of progress bar (progress bar filled after 20 seconds). You can regulate this number.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_xml, container, false)
        object : CountDownTimer(20000, 200) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                customView.setProgress(counter)
                counter++
            }

            override fun onFinish() {

            }
        }.start()

        return view
    }
```

And customView

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View

class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr) {


    private var paint: Paint
    private var radius: Float = 0f
    private var angle = 0f

    init {
        paint = Paint()
        paint.color = Color.GRAY
        paint.setAntiAlias(true)
        paint.strokeWidth = 5f
        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        Log.e("tag", "init")
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        radius = (width/2f -1f)
        paint.color = Color.GRAY
        canvas.drawCircle(width.toFloat()/2, height.toFloat()/2, radius, paint)
        paint.color = Color.GREEN
        val oval = RectF(0f,0f,width.toFloat()-2,width.toFloat()-2)
        canvas.drawArc(oval, -90f,angle,false ,paint)
    }

    fun setProgress(percent: Int) {
        angle = percent*3.6f
        invalidate()
    }

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x874.png

Comment: how to add arrow and text to it and also how will i update the progress bar while downloading the file?

Comment: It difficult link progress bar with progress of downloading file, but update progress you can use `invalidate` method, this method redraw custom view

Comment: @CosmicDev I edit my comment and add code for your case. You can change colors and text

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom layout that contains your progressBar, textView and imageView.

layout_custom_progressbar.xml

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Download PDF"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then add this layout in your desired activity using  tag and show or hide it using **visibility** property.

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    layout="@layout/layout_custom_progressbar"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: So is this progress bar can be updated while downloading any file to display the progress?

Comment: @CosmicDev yes you can update its progress state using **setProgress()**

Comment: ok thanks and how do i set that grey color of progress bar by default and green color at runtime?

Comment: Try this progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY) @CosmicDev

Comment: it is changing the color but it is not stopping the spin, i want to stop the spin and have a default grey color progress bar and updating the progress with green color.

Comment: I have answered your initial question and if it helped you, you can upvote the answer. And for your other questions, you can post another question. @CosmicDev

Comment: Its not an complete answer, I have displayed the image of the progress bar that i want to make and your code only works with 1 part of the answer. I can definitely upvote but can't accept it.